# How to represent visual studio embedded classes in a class diargam

Tags: c#, uml, class-diagram

I'm creating a class diagram for my project, which is a c# solution.

I think that textbox, button, etc.. are represented in the attribute section of the class.

I've used classes like Directory, StreamReader, etc...

Should I represent them as normal classes?
If so, what is the relationship between them and the class that uses them (ex : MainWindow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases I use stereotypes like `<<directory>>`, `<<button>>` etc. to make the use of the class more clear. The relation between your classes should be normal associations. You could use composition for windows that are composed of buttons, fields, etc.

The following shows two different button types which inherit from a general `Button` class and a text field composed in a window:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. so you mean that I should draw new classes even for buttons??

Comment: It depends on the level you are trying to model. Window elements are classes on their own. Maybe in embedded systems you can have a window that has elements represented as properties. But on "normal" systems they are classes on their own.

Comment: I did a small partial diagram according to your answer.. you mean like this??
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t876ke5u5tgpvmy/asd.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes. Looks perfectly ok. Who forced you to use RSA ;-)

Comment: Hehehehe.. it's just a homework -_-
well..thanks..your answer is accepted

Comment: One remark I overlooked before: You could use a stereotype for `Button` to describe the button type and for `Textfield` whether its a `<<Label>>` or `<<Input>>`. Not really needed but helps in many cases.

Comment: ok.. so in the class name section I write <<Button>> then the button name??

Comment: My last contact with RSA is more than 10 years ago. There should be a separate property to take the stereotype. It should then appear in the `<<>>` brackets on the diagram.

Comment: I have added an example diagram